# Why this angularjs code is not working?

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my html code, and it's not giving the proper output. Ιt's not working by using `{{expression}}`, that's why I use `ng-bind`. Βut still not working, although I use both the way to print the enter value. What is the mistake in this code?

Τhis is the output it's showing:

> firstname:
>
> lastname:
>
> fullname:`{{firstname}}`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng app>
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div>
            <label>first name:</label><input type="text" ng-model="firstname"/>
            <hr>
            <label> last name:<input type="text" ng-model="lastname"/><br><br></label>
            <h3>full name  <span ng-bind="firstname"> </span> {{firstname}} </h3>
    
    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ng app` should be `ng-app="yourAppName"`

Comment: yup now  I get it I am not using - in between ng and app by the way it will work without providing the name also because we need to provide name when we using controller or either separate js file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format your inline code so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also please use shorter sentences and proper punctuation such as comas and fullstops. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert this

```
<html ng app>
```

to this

```
<html ng-app>
```

Comment: ohhh  no shit ! what a silly mistake I am doing...thank you now it's working